# Django Test: error creating the test database: permission denied to copy database "template_postgis"

Tags: python, django, postgis, django-testing, geodjango

I am am working on setting up Django Project for `running tests`. But I am getting below error:

```
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to copy database "template_postgis"
```

**Note**: My default application's database is working fine. The `issue is happening while running tests`.

Complete stack trace is as:

```
moin@moin-pc:~/workspace/mozio$ python manage.py test --verbosity=3
nosetests --verbosity=3
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_my_db')...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to copy database "template_postgis"

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_mozio_db_test', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: must be owner of database test_mozio_db_test
```

Below is the DATABASE configuration of `setting.py`:

```
POSTGIS_VERSION = (2, 2, 2)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'my_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_pass',
        'HOST': '<HOST_IP',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_my_db',
        },
    }
}
```

Any help regarding this? Below are the steps I tried:

- Grant create DB access to user:

  ```
  ALTER USER my_user CREATEDB;
  ```
- Grant all privileges to user for `test_my_db` database:

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test_mozio_db_test to mozio;
  ```

---

**Edit**:
After fixing above issue, I was also getting error as:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 5:     "polygon" geometry(POLYGON,4326) NOT NULL,
```

Updated my answer to fix both the issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found how to fix this issue. The problem is that when I created `template_postgis`, I didn’t set it to be a `template`.

You can check it via doing:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_database;
```

You can fix it by setting `datistemplate=true` for `template_postgis` by running:

```
update pg_database set datistemplate=true where datname='template_postgis';
```

---

After that in case you are getting error related to `geometry` like:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 5:     "polygon" geometry(POLYGON,4326) NOT NULL,
```

That is because you need to add extension `postgix` with database. In order to fix this, add `postgis` to `template_postgis` like:

```
psql -d psql -d template_postgis -c 'create extension postgis;'
```

*Note*: You must be superuser to create this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Install packages first correctly.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

During installation postgres user is created automatically.

```
 sudo su - postgres
```

You should now be in a shell session for the postgres user. Log into a Postgres session by typing:

```
 psql

 CREATE DATABASE myproject;
```

In your settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the answer. On my system everything was installed and default application connection was working. But the issue was only with test database.

Comment: @Moinuddin as in error it is saying you are accessing templates databases which are automatically created. I don't know why you want to access them but better to create your own database and link it to settings.py

Comment: But if you are satisfied with your answer it's okay.